# Toggle button skin - center

Tags: android, toggle, skin

in our app we have some toggle buttons with custom skin. The problem is visible on next picture. The toggle indicator isn't centered well. This problem appears only on devices whit higher resolution...for example on Nexus 7

[image]

Here is some code how we have defined skin

```
<!-- TOGGLE -->
<style name="Toggle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/toggle_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/button_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/button_padding_right</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_bg_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/toggle_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

button_padding_left and button_padding_right is both 3dip

toggle_bg_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_bg_on" />       
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_bg_on" />        
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_bg_on" />        
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_bg_off" />  
</selector>
```

And yes the drawable images are centered correctly.

Thank you for any responce.

Comment: May be add `android:gravity="center"` to each of the items?

Comment: If you mean in "selector", that is not possible. And add android:gravity="center" to "toggle" in layout makes no changes.

Comment: Instead of:
`<item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_bg_selector</item>`
in the selector, try out this:
`<item>
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/toggle_bg_selector"
          android:gravity="center" />
 </item>`

Comment: <item> <bitmap android:src="@drawable/toggle_bg_selector" android:gravity="center" /> </item> in selector file causes the width of toggle is same as the image we use...so the toggle is shrinked

Comment: Ok, put the picture you mentioned in the beginning please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. It was a bad 9 patch picture. The scale area was 1 or 2 pixels wider on left side than on the right side.